# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, vagrant, urllib3

I am trying to make an API call on Google Maps Places API via python flask server. Please find the sample code:

```
response = requests.get(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' + urlencode(
            {'location': location, 'rankby': 'prominence','types' : 'tourist_attraction' , 'key': gmaps_key, 'radius': 6000}))
    # Read response as json
    resp_address = response.json()
    if resp_address['status'] == 'OK':
        resp_address = resp_address['results']

        places_dictionary = {}
```

As of now, this code is working fine when testing independently on the terminal. 
But when running it on localhost 5000, the API call fails and results in the below error:

(
Environment: Python 3.6
Virtual Environment: Vagrant
Flask Server )

############Making API call from Server

10.0.2.2 - - [20/Jun/2020 08:28:26] "GET /choose_trip/SFO HTTP/1.1" 500 -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/server.py", line 88, in homepage
    {'location': location, 'rankby': 'prominence','types' : 'tourist_attraction' , 'key': gmaps_key, 'radius': 6000}))
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/src/Major Project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='maps.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%2837.7749%2C+-122.4194%29&rankby=prominence&types=tourist_attraction&key=AIzaSyAgbtLGPnoZfOiu4a2EdmB7aEfnTLJ_Sd8&radius=6000 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4dfc1287f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

Tried to check it google maps URL and it works in the browser but somehow this is failing while executing it via localhost. (Also, my key's limitation is still unlimited and not consumed).